# PayPal Payout always DENIED (sandbox)

Tags: php, paypal

I am trying to test synchronized Payout for my PHP application but response from server is always the same and it points me to [INTERNAL_ERROR](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INTERNAL_ERROR). I am using `paypal/rest-api-sdk-php` I believe of version v1.0.0 (composer.json says nothing) - should be the newest in my JSON I have version set to `dev-master`.

```
try {
    /** @var PayoutBatch $payoutBatch */
    $payoutBatch = $payout->createSynchronous($apiContext);
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}

try {
    /** @var PayoutBatch $response */
    $response = Payout::get($payoutBatch->getBatchHeader()->getPayoutBatchId(), $apiContext);

    $status = $response->getBatchHeader()->getBatchStatus();

    if ($status === "SUCCESS") {
        //do some logic
    }

} catch (\Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

Have any of you experienced this issue?

Also a sub-question, don't PayPal PHP SDK has defined some constants where I can find message statuses?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help with this issue directly, but I can recommend that you take a look at my [PayPal PHP class library](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library) and use it instead.  It's a lot simpler to use than PayPal's SDK, and it's [compatible with Composer](https://packagist.org/packages/angelleye/paypal-php-library), too.

Comment: What about Payouts? Can your library handle them?

Comment: Yes, that would be done with the Pay API or the MassPay API. My library supports both.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please make sure you have [Payouts Enabled in your sandbox environment.](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/myapps) This allows you to get the proper scope that is required to make payout calls.

[image: Payout Settings]

However, if you have already done that and still failing, can you please try the samples out that are shipped along with SDK.

All you need to do is run one command, and you will have the samples running, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Samples#instructions)

```
php -f vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/sample/index.php
```

This will start a sample server, and allow you to play around it.

[image]

It has a payout samples, that you could just click and run. If those works, we can now make one tiny change to get samples to use your clientId and secret. Find [samples/bootstrap.php](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/bootstrap.php#L29) in sdk code, and change those clientId and secret, and run the samples again. If you get a failure, let me know and I could look further into that issue.

Comment: I've got Payouts enabled in my sandbox PayPal and also the samples are working. Only thing that doesn't working is my payout. Any suggestions?

Comment: When you say samples, are working, were you able to switch the clientId and Secret provided by default with one of yours ? This would be very helpful to know. Sorry for asking you to do this again and again, but it solves these issues really fast.

Find samples/bootstrap.php(https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/bootstrap.php#L29) in sdk code, and change those clientId and secret, and run the samples again. If you get a failure, let me know and I could look further into that issue.

Comment: Thank you for your cooperation. It fails with my `clientId` and `clientSecret` and I have Payouts checked in my configuration at Paypal sandbox. Should I send you some information about my sandbox account so you should check if further?

Also my live side respond the same (I have Payouts checked also). I wrote to your customer service but so far no answer so I am still waiting.

Comment: Can you create a issue here at https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/issues with your clientId only. DO NOT SEND YOUR Client Secret. I will forward that to make sure your clientId has proper scope for payouts. There have been cases, where even though the scope has been updated, the caches fails to update, and causes issue like this. Thanks